# Why chart.js display only one day?

Tags: mysql, charts, chart.js

In MySQL I have data of date like this
Day-Month-Year H D time

12-01-2016 23:00
13-01-2016 00:00

Chart.js code of display date:

```
type: 'time',
time: {

    displayFormats: {
        hour: 'DD-MM-YYYY h:mm a'
```

Chart.js stops on 12-01-16 23:00
Next date is      13-01-16 00:00

Why Chart.js can't show this 13-01-16 00:00 no mater if I change it to 13-01-16 00:10

After 13-01-16 00:00 i have 10 hours to show on chart :/

I whant to display date like: DD-MM-YYY

In SQL date is 12-01-2016 23:00 [MM-DD-YYYY]
but Chart.js display : 01-12-2016  Like I whant

I intentionally insert date in MYSQL like 12-01-2016 23:00 [MM-DD-YYYY]

[Chart.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0RUM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuQfU.png)
second .png excample is correct :)

Help

Comment: Then you should use `day ` instead of `hour`. For more: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-display-formats

Comment: Thank you I'm confused with the display of day month year something is wrong

Comment: ok I have it,we have to remember to use the same DATATIME format like in PhpMyAdmin in MySQL (in EXCEL etc)